# What priority does request.status == 200 have on actions?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to check the users friends, then echo them all in a certain box. The problem is that it deletes the code in the box (the groupchat.innerHTML = '';) but then it doesn't replace it with the this.responseText

Here is the code :

```
  function loadfriends() {
    var fullurl = "../backend/friends.php?loadfriends=true";
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", fullurl , false);
      request.onload = function(){
          if(request.status == 200){
            groupchat = document.getElementById("leftsmallbox");
            groupchat.innerHTML = '';
                groupchat.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
      }
      request.send();
    }
    setInterval(loadfriends, 15000);
```

Thanks

Comment: You might find it easier to use the Fetch API these days.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.onreadystatechange = ...` instead of `onload`. And request.open should be called after. See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: what do I put after the request.onreadystatechange = ... ?

Comment: nvm I forgot something

Comment: Exactly what you have after 'request.onload ='